# ElaaticSearch - extract info between tags in the Highlights field

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a field in our ElasticSearch index called `Terms Matched` and we populate that field at query time with the values that are tagged in the `Highlights` field of a given result.  The `Highlights` field is derived from our field called `Free Text`, which contains unstructured data.  The query is not a match phrase query - it looks for the words in the query to be within a certain distance of each other via a `span-multi` query.

So right now, an example could look like this:

```
Query: John Smith

Result:

Free Text: "Once upon a time, John Alexander Smith went to the market..."
Highlights: "Once upon a time, <em>John</em> Alexander <em>Smith</em> went to the market..."
Terms Matched: John Smith
```

Currently, the `Terms Matched` field is just a concatenation of the tags from `Highlights`.  What we want to do is have the `Terms Matched` field return the tags, AND anything between the tags, if there is more than one tag -  so in the above example the `Terms Matched` field would show "John Alexander Smith."

How could we accomplish this in ElasticSearch?

Comment: Can you try indexing data as shingles? This might work.

Comment: I’m new to the idea of shingles. I just read up on them and it certainly COULD help. Before we were to go re-index all our data, do you have experience with both shingles and highlights to the point that you think indexing as shingles would work for what I’m asking? Or even any anecdotal evidence?

Comment: I'll try it and will post as an answer. Bear with me 

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is working as you would expect.

This is mapping with shingles token filter configured. Shingles will produce combinations of searchable tokens (2 to 4 tokens per shingle).

```js
PUT /highlights
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "my_shingle"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "max_shingle_size": 4,
          "min_shingle_size": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Dummy document

```js
PUT /highlights/_doc/1
{
  "content": "Once upon a time, John Alexander Smith went to the market..."
}
```

And basic search query

```js
GET /highlights/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "John Smith"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "type": "plain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response, with correctly (hopefully) highlighted text:

```js
{
  "took" : 46,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.8111373,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "highlights",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.8111373,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "Once upon a time, John Alexander Smith went to the market..."
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "content" : [
            "Once upon a time, <em>John Alexander Smith</em> went to the market..."
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Yet again, you might need to tweak this quite a lot, but this should put you on right track.

Comment: Well this looks incredibly promising!  Give me a little time to experiment with this and assuming it works, I'll mark as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Stpete111 It might not work exactly as you expected, highlighting range, but that's the best I could come up with. Cheers! :)